# FFMPEG (2.5.7 ) Progress Bar from PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg, preg-match

i want to have the Progress bar of FFmpeg encoding.This is the Code which i am using to get the percentage value of encoding Process.

```
<?php
$content = @file_get_contents("with-logo/output.txt");
//echo $content;
if($content) {
    preg_match("/Duration: (.*?), start:/", $content, $matches);

    $rawDuration = $matches[1];

    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawDuration));
    $duration = floatval($ar[0]);
    //echo $duration;
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $duration += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $duration += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //get the time in the file that is already encoded
    preg_match_all("/time=(.*?) bitrate/", $content, $matches);

    $rawTime = array_pop($matches);

    //this is needed if there is more than one match
    if (is_array($rawTime)){$rawTime = array_pop($rawTime);}

    //rawTime is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawTime));
    $time = floatval($ar[0]);
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $time += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $time += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //calculate the progress
    $progress = round(($time/$duration) * 100);

    echo "Duration: " . $duration . "<br>";
    echo "Current Time: " . $time . "<br>";
    echo "Progress: " . $progress . "%";
}
?>
```

here is relevant log line form my FFMPEG Log files for Better Understanding.

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=   0.9kbits/s    
frame=   22 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.85 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=   33 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.30 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   43 fps= 20 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.69 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s
```

and this code is not returning the Value for `Duration` and as a result of this i am getting PHP warning and code is not calculating the Current percentage.

here is the PHP warning , which i am getting-

```
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /var/www/html/mm/progressbar.php
```

i think we can also calculate the percentage from the `time`but i have no idea, how can i make it work?

or any help to solve the Problem with Duration.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Before you run the ffMPEG command here, you should run the following command, and that will give you the duration.

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv 2>&1 | grep "Duration"
   Duration: 00:39:43.08, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 386 kb/s
```

You can then preg_match that  wtih `'/Duration: ([0-9]{*}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})/'` to get h, m, s and .s into variables.

**Long Answer**

There is another way you can handle. As opposed to using php-ffmpeg, simply work out what commands you need and run them directly using popen() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or proc_open() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

```
$cmd = "/path/to/ffmpeg -options";
$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @flush();
}
pclose($proc);
```

This will essentially hold the process open for you as the command runs, and grabs output from the screen as it happens.

So run it twice; once for the duration, and a second time for the actual conversion. You can then process the output line by line, and save progress to another file/database which can be read by other processes.

Remember to set the PHP timeout to > time it takes to process the file.

Comment: Hi @Robbbie!

the second Option which you have suggested , i will give a try soon but now for getting the value of Duration, i run the command manually on the shell which you suggested `ffmpeg /tmp/out.mp4 2>&1 | grep "Duration"` . and i didnt get any Feedback, it just stuck whitout any response.

Comment: Your instructions is missing the -i ?

Comment: oh man! i am sorry , i just missed it., you rock

thanks @ Robbie

Comment: I just want to clear one more thing. at the moment i have a webpage , where user just Put the File ID and then the file is searched in the storage and FFMPEG gets the input for the Encoding.

Right Now i am concatinating the Input list to the FFMPEG like this 
`ffmpeg -f concat -i /tmp/mylist.txt`

Comment: so firstly i need to Echo the file path into the mylist.txt file. i had to do like this because before FFmpeg was not taking the searched file path as a input and every TIme user wants to encoding the new FIle , i need to update the concat list and remove the Previous File path and Echo the New File with searched Path.for searching the file in the backgroud i am using linux `find` command , which i running via `ssh2_exec()` php function.

is there a way that i can directly concat the  return value of `find` and i dont need to maintain the Input file.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. For ssh2_exec, use the first comment on the page in the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) as that has an example of reading the results. If that's not giving you what you need, then I'm lost. You could also look at phpseclib (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) as that gives you better control.

Comment: `$command ='find /mnt/'.$year.' -name '.$_POST['MXF'].'.mxf';`
`$stream = ssh2_exec($con, $command)`
`$file = stream_get_contents($stream);`
and now if i directly Pass $file Varibale to the FFMPEG code from the web to Linux then i get the ERROR. 
`No such a file or directory exist`
but when i echo this value to the MYlist.txt and the Concat .txt file then it works perfect.

``usr/bin/ffmpeg -f concat -i  "'.$file.'"` --> this doesnt work

Comment: Isn't it the ffmpeg that can't be found? `usr/bin/ffmpeg`? Doesn't that need to start with a slash? `/usr/bin/ffmpeg ` But otherwise I have NO IDEA what MYlist.txt and Concat.txt is. Perhaps start another question with new issues, and post the code and you're asking new stuff.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i '.$FILE.' 2>&1 | grep "Duration"` this return me Null and here $FILE is the File Path-